# Can I forget ResultSetFuture in Cassandra java driver without facing memory leak?

Tags: java, asynchronous, memory-leaks, cassandra

I'm doing bunch of bulk deletes in my application. I want to submit the query using using `Session.executeAsync()` and forget the returned `ResultSetFuture` without explicitly calling `get()` method to return the result. will this cause memory leak? I have seen the same question has been asked about java `ExecutorService` which seems to be solved in java 7 and 8. The same rule applies for Cassandra driver? I'm using java 8 with Cassandra driver 2.1.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not hit any memory leaks doing that. That said, since your calling something asynchronously if you call it a lot (**lot**) with no throttling you could very well run out of memory by producing things faster then they can be processed.